# Getting the file name from dataframes Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get multiple file names to eventually write them as a key in a dictionary. All the file types will be a csv. Here what I have:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r"Documents\Data Import Template.csv")
df1= pd.read_csv(r"Customer Data.csv")
filename = glob.glob(os.path.join('path/*.csv'))

errors= {}

#here I am writing the file name as the key to the dict of errors that are found

mask = df1.apply(lambda c: c.isin(valid[c.name]))
df1.mask(mask|df1.eq(' ')).stack()

for r, v in df1.mask(mask|df1.eq(' ')).stack().iteritems():
    errors[filename]={
    "row": r[0],
    "column": r[1],
    "message": v + " is invalid"
}
```

I am getting a typeError: unhashable type:list

Comment: I believe `glob.glob` return a list, see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) so what you seem to want would be `errors[filename[0]]` or something like this

Comment: the glob.glob function is not making a list that contains any information. With the code I provided the list is empty but Im not sure why. @Ben.T

Comment: what is a bit weird in your code is that the path you are looking for the csv file into is called `path` (it is possible, just a bit unusual), would it be more something like `glob.glob(r"Documents/*.csv'))`?

Comment: The cause of the error is exactly what @Ben.T pointed out: `glob.glob()` returns a `list` (it doesn't matter if it is empty or not), which is not hashable, and therefore not eligible as a `dict` key.